# Unicity of complex key dictionaries in Go but not in Julia?

Tags: dictionary, struct, types, julia

In GO when I use a struct as a key for a map, there is an unicity of the keys.

For example, the following code produce a map with only one key : map[{x 1}:1]

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type MyT struct {
    A string
    B int
}

func main() {

    dic := make(map[MyT]int)

    for i := 1; i <= 10; i++ {
        dic[MyT{"x", 1}] = 1
    }

    fmt.Println(dic)
}

// result : map[{x 1}:1]
```

I Tried to do the same in Julia and I had a strange surprise :

This Julia code, similar to the GO one, produces a dictionary whith 10 keys !

```
    type MyT
        A::String
        B::Int64
    end

    dic = Dict{MyT, Int64}()

    for i in 1:10
        dic[MyT("x", 1)] = 1
    end

    println(dic)
    # Dict(MyT("x",1)=>1,MyT("x",1)=>1,MyT("x",1)=>1,MyT("x",1)=>1,MyT("x",1)=>1,MyT("x",1)=>1,MyT("x",1)=>1,MyT("x",1)=>1,MyT("x",1)=>1,MyT("x",1)=>1)

    println(keys(dic))
    # MyT[MyT("x",1),MyT("x",1),MyT("x",1),MyT("x",1),MyT("x",1),MyT("x",1),MyT("x",1),MyT("x",1),MyT("x",1),MyT("x",1)]
```

So what I did wrong ?

Thank you @DanGetz for the solution ! :

```
immutable MyT     # or struct MyT with julia > 0.6
    A::String
    B::Int64
end

dic = Dict{MyT, Int64}()

for i in 1:10
    dic[MyT("x", 1)] = 1
end

println(dic)         # Dict(MyT("x", 1)=>1)
println(keys(dic))   # MyT[MyT("x", 1)]
```

Comment: Just replace `type` with `immutable` or `struct` (new word for immutable) and things work like in Go. Indeed, when MyT is mutable, a `MyT("x",1)` might be different than a similarly constructed variable at a later point (for example by assigning `B` field to something else).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mutable values hash *by identity* in Julia, since without additional knowledge about what a type represents, one cannot know if two values with the same structure mean the same thing or not. Hashing mutable objects by value can be especially problematic if you mutate a value after using it as a dictionary key – this is not a problem when hashing by identity since the identity of a mutable object remains the same even when it is modified. On the other hand, it's perfectly safe to hash immutable objects by value – since they cannot be mutated, and accordingly that is the default behavior for immutable types. In the given example, if you make `MyT` immutable you will automatically get the behavior you're expecting:

```
immutable MyT # `struct MyT` in 0.6
    A::String
    B::Int64
end

dic = Dict{MyT, Int64}()

for i in 1:10
    dic[MyT("x", 1)] = 1
end
```

```
julia> dic
Dict{MyT,Int64} with 1 entry:
  MyT("x", 1) => 1

julia> keys(dic)
Base.KeyIterator for a Dict{MyT,Int64} with 1 entry. Keys:
  MyT("x", 1)
```

For a type holding a `String` and an `Int` value that you want to use as a hash key, immutability is probably the right choice. In fact, immutability is the right choice more often than not, which is why the keywords introducing structural types has been change in 0.6 to `struct` for immutable structures and `mutable struct` for mutable structures – on the principle that people will reach for the shorter, simpler name first, so that should be the better default choice – i.e. immutability.

As @ntdef has written, you can change the hashing behavior of your type by overloading the `Base.hash` function. However, his definition is incorrect in a few respects (which is probably our fault for failing to document this more prominently and thoroughly):

1. The method signature of `Base.hash` that you want to overload is `Base.hash(::T, ::UInt)`.
2. The `Base.hash(::T, ::UInt)` method must return a `UInt` value.
3. If you are overloading `Base.hash`, you should also overload `Base.==` to match.

So this would be a correct way to make your mutable type hash by value (new Julia session required to redefine `MyT`):

```
type MyT # `mutable struct MyT` in 0.6
    A::String
    B::Int64
end

import Base: ==, hash

==(x::MyT, y::MyT) = x.A == y.A && x.B == y.B

hash(x::MyT, h::UInt) = hash((MyT, x.A, x.B), h)

dic = Dict{MyT, Int64}()

for i in 1:10
    dic[MyT("x", 1)] = 1
end
```

```
julia> dic
Dict{MyT,Int64} with 1 entry:
  MyT("x", 1) => 1

julia> keys(dic)
Base.KeyIterator for a Dict{MyT,Int64} with 1 entry. Keys:
  MyT("x", 1)
```

This is kind of annoying to do manually, but the [AutoHashEquals](https://github.com/andrewcooke/AutoHashEquals.jl) package automates this, taking the tedium out of it. All you need to do is prefix the `type` definition with the `@auto_hash_equals` macro:

```
using AutoHashEquals

@auto_hash_equals type MyT # `@auto_hash_equals mutable struct MyT` in 0.6
    A::String
    B::Int64
end
```

**Bottom line:**

- If you have a type that should have value-based equality and hashing, seriously consider making it immutable.
- If your type really has to be mutable, then think hard about whether it's a good idea to use as a hash key.
- If you really need to use a mutable type as a hash key with value-based equality and hashing semantics, use the `AutoHashEquals` package.

Comment: Oops: first time around I forgot to include the actual `hash` and `==` method definitions to make mutable hashing by value work! Fixed.

Answer (score 4):

You did not do anything wrong.  The difference between the languages is in how they choose to hash a struct when using it as a key in the map/Dict.  In go, structs are hashed by their **values** rather than their **pointer addresses**.  This allows programmers to more easily implement multidimensional maps by using structs rather than maps of maps.  See [this blog post](https://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action#TOC_5.) for more info.

### Reproducing Julia's Behavior in Go

To reproduce Julia's behavior in go, redefine the map to use a pointer to `MyT` as the key type:

```golang
func main() {

    dic := make(map[MyT]int)
    pdic := make(map[*MyT]int)

    for i := 1; i <= 10; i++ {
        t := MyT{"x", 1}
        dic[t] = 1
        pdic[&t] = 1
    }

    fmt.Println(dic)
    fmt.Println(pdic)
}
```

Here, `pdic` uses the pointer to a `MyT` struct as its key type.  Because each `MyT` created in the loop has a different memory address, the key will be different.  This produces the output:

```
map[{x 1}:1]
map[0x1040a140:1 0x1040a150:1 0x1040a160:1 0x1040a180:1 0x1040a1b0:1 0x1040a1c0:1 0x1040a130:1 0x1040a170:1 0x1040a190:1 0x1040a1a0:1]
```

You can play with this [on play.golang.org](https://play.golang.org/p/RpTLbNMON6).  Unlike in Julia (see below), the way the map type is implemented go means you cannot specify a custom hashing function for a user-defined struct.

### Reproducing Go's Behavior in Julia

Julia uses the function `Base.hash(::K, ::UInt)` to hash keys for its `Dict{K,V}` type.  While it doesn't explicitly say so in the documentation, the default hashing algorithm uses the output from `object_id`, as you can see in [the source code](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/v0.5.2/base/hashing.jl#L10).  To reproduce go's behavior in Julia, define a new `hash` function for your type that hashes the values of the struct:

```julia
Base.hash(t::MyT, h::Uint) = Base.hash((t.A, t.B), h)
```

Note that you should also define the == operator in the same way to guarantee `hash(x)==hash(y)` implies `isequal(x,y)`, [as mentioned in the documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.hash).

However, the easiest way to get Julia to act like go in your example is to redefine `MyT` as `immutable`.  As an immutable type, Julia will hash `MyT` by its value rather than its `object_id`.  As an example:

```julia
immutable MyT
    A::String
    B::Int64
end

dic = Dict{MyT, Int64}()

for i in 1:10
    dic[MyT("x", 1)] = 1
end

dic[MyT("y", 2)] = 2

println(dic) # prints "Dict(MyT("y",2)=>2,MyT("x",1)=>1)"
```

Comment: Thank you very much everybody to take all this time to produce such interesting answers !

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**  Please refer to @StefanKarpinski's answer. The `Base.hash` function must return a `UInt` for it to be a valid hash, so my example won't work. Also there's some funkiness regarding user defined types which involves recursion.

The reason you get 10 different keys is due to the fact that Julia uses the `hash` function when determining the key to a dict. In this case, I'm guessing that it's using the address of the object in memory as the key for the dictionary. If you'd like to explicitly make `(A,B)` the unique key, you'll need to override the `hash` function for your particular type, with something like this:

```
Base.hash(x::MyT) = (x.A, x.B)
```

That will replicate the Go behavior, with only one item in the `Dict`.

[Here's the documentation to the `hash` function.](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/base/#Base.hash)

Hope that helps!

Comment: That is not quite correct, since `hash` needs to return an integer value. You want something like `hash(x::MyT, h) = hash(x.A, hash(x.B, h))`.

Comment: My mistake. After a second read through the docs, it makes sense now, although you might want to highlight that the return type must be a `UInt`.

Comment: actually @JeffBezanson, does it need to be strictly a `UInt` or will any `Int` do?