# How to use haskey() and in() functions with complex dictionnary keys in Julia?

Tags: dictionary, go, struct, julia

haskey() and in() functions are very useful to test the content of dictionaries in Julia :

```
julia> dict = Dict("a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 3, "d" => 4, "e" => 5)
Dict{String,Int64} with 5 entries:
  "c" => 3
  "e" => 5
  "b" => 2
  "a" => 1
  "d" => 4

julia> haskey(dict, "a")
true

julia> in(("a" => 1), dict)
true
```

but I was surprised by their behavior with complex keys :

```
julia> immutable MyT
           A::String
           B::Int64
       end

julia> a = Dict(MyT("Tom",191)=>1,MyT("Bob",20)=>1,MyT("Jo",315)=>1,MyT("Luc",493)=>1)
Dict{MyT,Int64} with 4 entries:
  MyT("Tom",191) => 1
  MyT("Jo",315)  => 1
  MyT("Bob",20)  => 1
  MyT("Luc",493) => 1

julia> keys(a)
Base.KeyIterator for a Dict{MyT,Int64} with 4 entries. Keys:
  MyT("Tom",191)
  MyT("Jo",315)
  MyT("Bob",20)
  MyT("Luc",493)

julia> haskey(a, MyT("Tom",191))
false

julia> in((MyT("Tom",191) => 1), a)
false
```

What I did wrong ?
Thank you very much for your comments !

Thanks to @Michael K. Borregaard, I can propose this solution :

```
a = Dict{MyT, Int64}()

keyArray = Array{MyT,1}()
keyArray = [MyT("Tom",191),MyT("Bob",20),MyT("Jo",315),MyT("Luc",493)]

for i in keyArray
    a[i] = 1
end

println(a)
# Dict(MyT("Tom",191)=>1,MyT("Tom",191)=>1,MyT("Luc",493)=>1,MyT("Jo",315)=>1,MyT("Luc",493)=>1,MyT("Bob",20)=>1,MyT("Jo",315)=>1,MyT("Bob",20)=>1)

keyArray[1]            # MyT("Tom",191)
haskey(a, keyArray[1]) # true
```

But I have to store keys in a separate array. This means that can't warranty the unicity of the keys which is the strength of the dictionaries and why I choose to use it :(

So I have to use another step :

```
unique(keyArray)
```

Another better solution :

```
function CompareKeys(k1::MyT, k2::MyT)
    if k1.A == k2.A &&  k1.B == k2.B
        return true
    else 
        return false
    end
end

function ExistKey(k::MyT, d::Dict{MyT, Int64})
    for i in keys(d)
        if CompareKeys(k, i)
            return true
        end
    end
    return false
end

a = Dict(MyT("Tom",191)=>1,MyT("Bob",20)=>1,MyT("Jo",315)=>1,MyT("Luc",493)=>1)

ExistKey(MyT("Tom",192),a) # false

ExistKey(MyT("Tom",191),a) # true
```

Compared to Julia, Go is more straightforward for this problem :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type MyT struct {
    A string
    B int
}

func main() {

    dic := map[MyT]int{MyT{"Bob", 10}: 1, MyT{"Jo", 21}: 1}

    if _, ok := dic[MyT{"Bob", 10}]; ok {
        fmt.Println("key exists")
    }
}
// answer is "key exists"
```

Comment: Hello again, Fred!  See [Stefan's answer from your question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44311316/5075720).  As [Michael K. Borregaard points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44326922/5075720), it has to do with the fact that, even for immutable structs, `hash(a::MyT) == hash(b::MyT)` does not automatically imply `isequals(a::MyT, b::MyT)`.

Comment: Thanks @PaSTE ! Do you think that the solution I wrote, with a separate unique key array, is the best ?

Comment: "Best" is difficult to evaluate.  If you are comfortable with the code and it serves your purposes, then who am I to say this is not best for you?  I think the solution you wrote might be cumbersome and memory-inefficient if the number of keys becomes large.  On top of that, `ExistsKey`, as written, runs in O(N) time, while looking up by hash value runs in roughly O(1) time.  Unless you know you have a very small number of keys to deal with, I would suggest implementing `hash` and `isequals` (or `==`), as [given below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44331242/5075720).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to teach your `MyT` type that you want it to consider equality in terms of its composite fields:

```
julia> immutable MyT
           A::String
           B::Int64
       end
       import Base: ==, hash
       ==(x::MyT, y::MyT) = x.A == y.A && x.B == y.B
       hash(x::MyT, h::UInt) = hash(x.A, hash(x.B, hash(0x7d6979235cb005d0, h)))

julia> a = Dict(MyT("Tom",191)=>1,MyT("Bob",20)=>1,MyT("Jo",315)=>1,MyT("Luc",493)=>1)
Dict{MyT,Int64} with 4 entries:
  MyT("Jo", 315)  => 1
  MyT("Luc", 493) => 1
  MyT("Tom", 191) => 1
  MyT("Bob", 20)  => 1

julia> haskey(a, MyT("Tom",191))
true

julia> in((MyT("Tom",191) => 1), a)
true
```

Comment: @Matt.B. , could you explain how did you obtain this address "0x7d6979235cb005d0" and what it means ? Thanks !

Comment: Yup, I just did a `rand(UInt64)`.  The value itself isn't significant; it just needs to be somewhat unique so you don't end up hashing `MyT("Jo",315)` the same as the tuple `("Jo", 315)` or someone else's `YourT("Jo",315)`.  Grabbing a random number is a great way to do that.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of good answers here, I'd just like to add a subtlety: this is partly because `==` calls `===` rather than recursively calling `==` when checking for structural equality, and partly because equal (`==`) strings are not generally identical (`===`) currently. Specifically, the fact that `MyT("foo", 1) != MyT("foo", 1)` is because `"foo" !== "foo"`.

Strings are only "immutable by convention" – they are technically mutable, but Julia doesn't expose APIs for mutating them and encourages you not to mutate them. You can, however, access their underlying bytes and mutate that, which allows you to write a program that distinguishes two strings by getting by mutating one and not the other. That means that they cannot be `===` in the sense of Henry Baker's ["EGAL" predicate](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.23.9999) (also [here](http://home.pipeline.com/~hbaker1/ObjectIdentity.html)). If you have an immutable type with only "primitive" type fields, then this does not happen:

```
julia> immutable MyT2 # `struct MyT2` in 0.6
           A::Float64
           B::Int
       end

julia> x = MyT2(1, 1)
MyT2(1.0, 1)

julia> y = MyT2(1, 1)
MyT2(1.0, 1)

julia> x == y
true

julia> x === y
true
```

I have [already proposed](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/4648) that we change this and have `==` recursively call `==`. This should be fixed, someone just needs to do the work. Moreover, in Julia 1.0 we could make Strings truly immutable rather than merely immutable by convention, and therefore have `"foo" === "foo"` be true. I've created [an issue](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/22193) to discuss and track this change.

Comment: By the way, I'm glad you brought up `"foo" !== "foo"`.  This feature bit me in an analysis not too long ago.  While I understand the reasons from an implementation point of view, `"foo" !== "foo"` just feels like it's more trouble on the support side than it's worth on the implementation side...

Comment: Yes, it would be good to have `"foo" === "foo"`, but that goes hand-in-hand with making Strings genuinely immutable, which is currently not the case. Otherwise you're just making up the meaning of `===` which is not ok.

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a new object in the `haskey` call. But two objects created by `MyT("Tom", 191)` are just two different MyT objects with the same field values.

Instead, do

```
key1 = MyT("Tom", 191)
a = Dict(key1 => 1)
haskey(a, key1)
```

see also

```
key2 = MyT("Tom", 191)
key1 == key2 # false
```

A julia-ideomatic way to deal with this would be to define an `==` method for MyT objects, so two objects are equal if they have the same field values. That would allow you to use them like you do.

It depends whether you need the type to be complex. Another easy and performant way to do what you want is to use a Tuple as the key:

```
a = Dict(("Tom", 191) => 1)
haskey(a, ("Tom", 191)) # true
a[("Tom", 191)] # 1
```

Comment: Thank you @Michael K. Borregaard. It means that I have to construct a separate array of keys. It is much easier in GO :  _, ok := dic[MyT{"Bob", 10}] works perfectly.

Comment: I think it is a common observation that some objectives are easier in some languages :-) The julian-ideomatic way to do this would be to define a new method for `==` that dispatches on your type.

Comment: I've edited the answer to suggest another approach as well that is more similar to what you know from Go.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be similar to Matt's, but a bit simpler(?). Tuples are perfectly valid dictionary keys, so I would simply overload the relevant functions to convert your type back and forth to a tuple:

```julia
julia> immutable M; A::String; B::Int64; end
julia> import Base: =>, haskey, in
julia> =>(a::M, b) = (a.A, a.B)=>b
julia> haskey(a::Dict, b::M) = haskey(a, (b.A, b.B))
julia> in(a::Pair{M, Int64}, b::Int64) = in((a.first.A,a.first.B)=>a.second,b)
```

```julia
julia> a = Dict(M("Dick", 10)=>1, M("Harry", 20)=>2)
Dict{Tuple{String,Int64},Int64} with 2 entries:
  ("Dick", 10)  => 1
  ("Harry", 20) => 2

julia> haskey(a, M("Dick", 10))
true

julia> in(M("Dick", 10)=>1, a)
true
```

> "Compared to Julia, Go is more straightforward for this problem"

True. It also happens to be more error-prone (depending on your perspective). If you wanted to differentiate between two objects (used as keys) that do *not* correspond to the same object in memory, then Go's approach of simply testing 'value equality' would have landed you in trouble here (though one could argue 'value equality' generally makes more sense when comparing 'keys').

Comment: or, skip the whole type stuff and use tuples to begin with :p

Comment: This kind of piece-meal method extension is really fragile and will likely lead to frustration.  You're effectively teaching _some_ of the Dict machinery that you want your type to act like tuples, but not all of it.  Check out `methodswith(Dict, true)` to see everything you'd need to change, including `getindex`, `setindex!`, `push!`, ….

Comment: Matt's solution is the canonical one, I hasten to add (as implied by the documentation for `isequal` and `hash`). Just mentioning the tuple point here out of sheer interest. :)

Comment: @MattB. hah, just beat me to it :D

Comment: @MattB. yes I agree. In fact, I think you should mention this in your answer! (i.e. that your suggestion is the canonical way as recommended by the documentation, respecting the Dict interface and requiring no other overloading)